# video.js responsive not working

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I have been using video.js for a while and was looking for a responsive solution. I saw that 4.6 claimed to be so but cannot get to work. And I find nothing in the documentation about making it responsive. I basically just need it to stay at 100% of the container and maintain its aspect ratio. If I leave the width/height off it defaults small. 100% will work on width but not sure what to put for height. Tried to use CSS on the id of the video tag, didn't work.

The daverupert.com method works for the older version of video.js but would not work with 4.6.

If it is documented somewhere a link would be helpful or any ideas on how someone else has made video.js 4.6 responsive.

Also, the loading animation is not showing.

Answer (score 18):

You could add this to the data-setup:

```
data-setup='{"fluid": true}'
```

or depending on your video aspect/ratio add the following class to the  container which does the same thing:

```
vjs-16-9
```

or

```
vjs-4-3
```

This codepen is another approach

https://codepen.io/dotdreaming/pen/CnLeD

Comment: Where has "fluid": true been all my life? This is exactly what I have been looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

This is the code I use for all my responsive players.

**First add a responsive wrapper**

```
<div class="video-js-responsive-container vjs-hd">
    <video .... standard videojs code ... >
        ... sources ...
    </video>
</div>
```

I use vjs-hd and vjs-sd to differentiate between 16:9 and 4:3

**Then set up the classes and css for it**

```
.video-js-responsive-container.vjs-hd {
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}
.video-js-responsive-container.vjs-sd {
    padding-top: 75%;
}
.video-js-responsive-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.video-js-responsive-container .video-js {
    height: 100% !important; 
    width: 100% !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I know using `!important` is frowned upon, but its reliable when overwriting other css classes.

The wrapper class `video-js-resonsive-container` will automatically size it self to 100% of the parent container while maintaining a height in ratio to the width.

Adapted from: http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: Note that 56.25% is (9/16)*100.  So this value assumes 16x9 is your HD aspect ratio, and the 75% would be based on (3/4)*100.   If your video uses different dimensions simply use (height/width)*100.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks.  I also ended up adding this as well:
`window.VIDEOJS_NO_DYNAMIC_STYLE = true`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the css of control bar to make the player responsive.
One way is to use the media queries. I did it by this way and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the full code suggested by VideoJS with the other file formats declared

```
  Below is the full code suggested by VideoJS with the other file formats declared

<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
```

Comment: I added example_option true which I had not seen anywhere. It works somewhat. When I adjust my browser window it will step down a couple of times. But when viewing on iPhone it does not format to that size rendering the rest of the page out of its layout. I looked through the css for a place to adjust but couldn't find. Any ideas?